# Is that my problems? If travel agent didn't ask me to get transit visa?

Tags: transit-visas

[image]

As above picture - brought a return flight ticket from London to buenos aires and transit at JFK airport. I didn't know a transit visa is needs until I went to check in today at Gatwick airport. The travel agent didn't mention to me that I need a visa for transit with Argentina passport holder. I was so annoying and didn't know what to do for the last minute. I phoned the travel agent and he said nothing to do with him.  He is just selling ticket. If I need to change the date with the same itinerary with same airline and it will cost me £768 just to change the date. My question is there any help for this critical situation?

Comment: @HenningMakholm not a true duplicate as that one refers to airlines, and this question is about travel agents.  Ultimately the answer is the same - it comes down to whats in the contract and local law.  Do travel agents have an inherent requirement to inform the traveller about required visas?  Depends on local consumer law and the contract between the traveller and the travel agent.  In most circumstances, the traveller is 100% responsible for the visa requirements.

Comment: You could/should contact the ABTA https://www.abta.com/  .

Comment: [My answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/131697/1480) concerning changes to travel document requirements also applies here: ultimately, it is the traveler who must check that he or she has met all entry and transit requirements.

Comment: As the actual traveller, yes, it will be your problem....

Comment: Did the travel agent even know that you would be traveling with an Argentine passport?

Comment: It is your problem, but if you had good contacts with your travel agent (not just website or/and booking, but also consultations/recommendations), the travel agent did a bad job. Still your problem but I would change TA. -- but it is not infrequent. Last time TA proposed me transfer between two "NY" airports. It is sad that we should double check the work of TA (the experts)

Comment: Definitely, if this is a travel agent you have a regular relationship with, it would definitely be the end of that relationship.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a Visa is always the traveler's problem.

Only the traveler will be there to answer questions about the required documentation whether on boarding or landing stage. No one will ask about the travel agent who didn't advise well.

As unfortunate as it is, and i feel sorry for your considerable loss; This was mostly caused by lack of due diligence and sans a travel insurance policy (which would accept this claim; hard to find one) there is not much recourse available for recovering any of that amount.

Here is what British Airways has to say

> If you're looking to make a smooth start to your journey, you need to make sure you have the right documents, such as a valid passport and the relevant visas.
>
> To help, we've summarised some of the key considerations and requirements here - but it's not a full list of all possible requirements around the world. It's your responsibility to ensure you have the right documents to be allowed to travel.

[British Airways](https://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/information/passports-visas-and-api)

Comment: Sorry, I have rolled back the edit because it significantly deviates from this answer's premise.

Comment: As far as I am aware (which is admittedly not very far) most travel insurance will not cover losses attributable to the failure to obtain necessary travel documents.

Comment: I know even lesser to be honest, But i still threw that in because the world is so big i just couldn't discredit all insurance policies with a blanket statement. My own insurance company doesn't cover for it, as rightly pointed by you.

Answer (score 1):

My question is there any help for this critical situation? **No**, Sorry. This happens to many frequent travellers. Book it as learning money and be thankful that it doesn't cost you more (No what what it costs you, there are unlucky souls out there who have lost more (missed their own wedding)

My advice, buy the next direct flight to EZE and figure out if you can get a transit visa for your return flight while in Argentina. Else, get a direct return too. Search online say though skyscanner or similar site and cut out the unhelpful middelmen.